# No module named pyspark in mac

Tags: pyspark

I have configured my `.bash_profile` like below . please let me know if anything i'm missing here . I'm getting

> No module named pyspark

```py
# added by Anaconda3 5.2.0 installer
export PATH=/Users/pkumar5/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home


# spark configuration
export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master "local[2]"'
```

i'm trying use pyspark in jupyter notebook , I'm getting error called "No module named pyspark" .Please . help me out to resolve.

Comment: Have you installed PySpark?

Comment: yes i've installed pyspark , Few days back i'm able to use pyspark and it's feature . But now i'm getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to define the correct `$PYTHONPATH` (this is where Python looks for modules).

Also something you might want to check: if you have installed `pyspark` correctly, it might be that you installed it for Python 3 while your Jupyter notebook kernel is running Python 2, so switching kernel would solve the issue.